# Can you trigger an AWS lambda function when a file is uploaded to a specific folder in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I wish to trigger an AWS lambda function I upload a file to a specific folder in S3. There are multiple folders in the s3 bucket now. Is this possible and how do i do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [Configure Amazon S3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), filtering on object key prefixes (and/or suffixes).

See [Configuring notifications with object key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering). A prefix could be `dogs/`, for example. That way, all uploads to a key beginning with `dogs/`, e.g. `dogs/alsatian.png` would notify.

Note that you probably don't actually have *any* folders in your S3 bucket, just objects, unless you created them using the AWS Console. There really aren't any folders in S3.

Comment: s3 --> event notifications --> trigger a lambda function?

Comment: @Yiffany yes, but not 100% sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: is this kind of event custom or default? because we have way too many events. [ref](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/pricing/#:~:text=AWS%20default%20service%20events)

Comment: @Yiffany if you have a question with details, I'd encourage you to ask a new question rather than try to address it here in comments. S3 events are something you actively configure and choose to handle.